# htaccess rewrite server error

Tags: .htaccess, xampp

Hi guys experimenting with .htaccess with XAMPP on my localhost, I have checked with phpinfo() if mod_rewrite is loaded and it is, so that shouldnt be the problem..

This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA, L]
```

and this is the error it gives on every page

```
SERVER ERROR

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.
```

Whats wrong with my htaccess or XAMPP? :)

Comment: Is `index.php` being executed? What is the `url` param that gets passed in?

Comment: is the file index.php realy exists ?

Comment: index is being passed in, and yes index.php does really exist :)

Answer (score 1):

$url was empty, make sure you echo out !